# Replace terms without symbolic term

Tags: replacement, rule

I have a variety of terms that have coefficients of what I'll call $c_x$ and terms that are without this coefficient. I have a variable $U$, and would like to substitute powers of $U^2 \to d$ but only if the terms do not contain $c_x$.

I can easily do this if I want to replace only terms *with* $c_x$ but not *without*.

In a minimal example I would like to go from:

```
U + U^2 + c_x U + c_x U^2
% /. unknownRule
Out[1]>> U + d + c_x U + c_x U^2
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
expr = U + U^2 + cx U + cx U^2
```

**1.** Using a single replacement rule

```
expr /.  (_. | Except[cx])  U^2 -> d
```

> ```
> d + U + cx U + U^2
> ```

**2.** Using two replacement rules:

```
expr /. {p : cx U^2 -> p, U^2 -> d}
```

> ```
> d + U + cx U + cx U^2
> ```

How this works: The first rule keeps a part that matches the pattern `cx U^2` as is *and* prevents the second rule from touching it.

[`ReplaceAll >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html):

[image]

Comment: In the second example, does the notation `p : ...` imply something about it being a temporary replacement that is reverted after? Thanks for the answer by the way, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @akozi, `p : cx U^2 -> p` is shorter form for `cx U^2 -> cx U^2`.  The way it works is as follows: `ReplaceAll` tries the first rule in the  rules list (that is, the rule  `p : cx U^2 -> p`) on each part (that is, the parts `U`, `U^2` , `cx U` and `cx U^2`) and makes the replacement for parts that match the LHS of the pattern (that is, it _replaces_ `cx U^2`  _with itself_ ). Then it tries the second rule (`U^2 ->d`) on _all parts_ _**except the parts that are already replaced by previous rules**_ (in this case, the part `cx U^2`)  and it finds `U^2` matching its LHS and replaces it with `d`.

Answer (score 5):

First, note that underscores cannot be used in symbol names, so the `c_x` in your code example may not have the meaning that you intended.

We can make the substitution for $U^2$ only in the terms containing $c_x$ like this

```
expr = U + U^2 + cx U + cx U^2;

Plus @@ Cases[expr, β_ :> If[MemberQ[β, cx], β /. U^2 -> d, β]]

(*  cx d + U + cx U + U^2  *)
```

And, similarly, in the terms *not* containg `cx` like this

```
Plus @@ Cases[expr, β_ :> If[MemberQ[β, cx], β, β /. U^2 -> d]]

(*  d + U + cx U + cx U^2  *)
```

A slightly shorter way to obtain the same results is

```
If[MemberQ[#, cx], # /. U^2 -> d, #] &  /@  expr  (*  cx d + U + cx U + U^2  *)

If[MemberQ[#, cx], #, # /. U^2 -> d] &  /@  expr  (* d + U + cx U + cx U^2  *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the note about `c_x`. So the last two arguments of the `If` command are substituting differently depending on if the first conditional is true or false. And so swapping the order changes which is replaced? Very cool! Thank you!